# SQL Query Data Collect

Tags: vb.net, mysql, sql

I have a SQL server table that has a list of Usernames and a list of points ranging from 1 to 10,000.

I want to display the number of points in my VB.NET program from the username given. For example, if I type in "john" in the first box the program will give me a message box saying whatever amount of points "john" has. I'm not really sure about SQL queries so please help me out here.

This is the Table Structure:

```
Usernames       Points
-----------------------------
John            20
Kate            40
Dan             309
Smith           4958
```

Comment: Is your table setup so that John will have multiple rows, each with a point value?  Or is it just one row with one point value?

Comment: Can you post the table structures?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the structure of the table, a suitable query is one of these:

```
select sum(points) as points
from usernames
where name='username';
```

or

```
select points
from usernames
where name='username';
```

or

```
select count(*) as points
from usernames
where name='username';
```

Comment: Wait in the second one don't I need an asterik after select :

select * points?

Comment: The second one assumes there is one entry per username with a corresponding field containing all the user's points, so no, it doesn't need anything more.